# Scanning Internal IP range for something running on port 9922 VBNet

Tags: vb.net, basic

I work for a clocking systems company, and sometimes don't have access to router and other tools to find something on network.

So I've made this but get errors. I need to be able to scan internal network of something on port 9922, TCP.

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Text
Module Module1
    Dim portStart As Integer
    Dim portEnd As Integer
    Dim lngPort As Long
    Dim lngRange As Long
    Dim txtHost1 As String
    Dim txtHost2 As String
    Dim txtHost As String
    Dim openPorts As Integer
    Dim closedPorts As Integer
    Dim range As String
    Dim lgnRange2 As Long
    Sub Main()
        Console.Write("Range Start: (For example 192.168.1.1 = 192.168.1. ")
        range = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.Write("Host to: Example 1 ")
        txtHost1 = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.Write("Host from: Example 254 ")
        txtHost2 = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.Write("Port: (9922 for Face Rec By default)")
        portEnd = Console.ReadLine()
        For lngRange = txtHost1 To txtHost2

        Next
        For lgnRange2 = range + lngRange
            Dim myTcpClient As New TcpClient()
            Try
                myTcpClient.Connect(lngPort, portEnd)
                Console.WriteLine("Host: " + txtHost + " : ")
                Console.WriteLine("  Port " + lngPort.ToString() + " : Open :")
                openPorts += 1
                myTcpClient.Close()
            Catch ex As SocketException
                Console.WriteLine("Host: " + txtHost + " : ")
                Console.WriteLine("  Port " + lngPort.ToString() + " : Closed :")
                ' Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                closedPorts += 1
                Console.Write("    " & openPorts.ToString & " open port(s) : ")
                Console.Write("     " & closedPorts.ToString & " closed port(s) : ")

                Console.Beep()
                Console.Write(txtHost + " : " + portStart.ToString + " - " + portEnd.ToString + " : Scanned Sucessfully")

            End Try
        Next
    End Sub
    Public Class psAPP
        Public Shared Sub Main()

        End Sub
    End Class
End Module
```

Comment: You should provide more details than "So i've made this but get errors" - what errors on what lines?  Runtime or compile errors? etc.  Review [ask] for more tips.

Comment: This line doesn't look valid `For lgnRange2 = range + lngRange`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response,

Comment: that's where I get the error, but i'm not sure if it would work, how do i make is so i put 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.254 and it will scan everything between them

Answer (score 0):

A `For` loop needs a numeric start and end, so you will need to convert your `txtHost1` and `txtHost2` variables to integers.  The [`TcpClient.Connect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbhht5w(v=vs.110).aspx) call will need either an `IPAddress` or a host name built from your hard-coded prefix and the current host number.  So, your loop could look something like (untested):

```
Option Strict On
Option Infer On
'...
For i = Integer.Parse(txtHost1) To Integer.Parse(txtHost2)
    Dim remoteAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1." & i)
    Try
        Using myTcpClient = New TcpClient()
            myTcpClient.Connect(remoteAddr, Integer.Parse(portEnd))
        End Using
        Console.WriteLine("Host: " + txtHost + " : ")
        Console.WriteLine("  Port " + lngPort.ToString() + " : Open :")
        openPorts += 1
    Catch ex As SocketException
        Console.WriteLine("Host: " + txtHost + " : ")
        Console.WriteLine("  Port " + lngPort.ToString() + " : Closed :")
        closedPorts += 1
    End Try
Next
Console.Write("    " & openPorts.ToString & " open port(s) : ")
Console.Write("     " & closedPorts.ToString & " closed port(s) : ")
```